# composition compared to other methods, what are the differences for the given situation?

Tags: java, android, composition

for use as java classes in Android, of the two methods, method 1 and method 2 shown below,  what are the differences between them, if there are any, and what are the disadvantages of either method?

```
  public class HelperClass {

      int variableValue = 2;

         public HelperClass() {

         }

  }
```

method 1

```
 public class TesterOne {

     public TesterOne() {

     }

     public void doSomething() {

       HelperClass mHelperClass = new HelperClass();

         int getValue = mHelperClass.variableValue;

    }

 }
```

method 2

```
  public class TesterOne {

  HelperClass mHelperClass;

  public TesterOne(){

  }

      public void doSomething(){

          int getValue = mHelperClass.variableValue;

      }

  }
```

Comment: method2 is wrong with out making variableValue static, you can't access varrable name without instantiating a object or make it static or class type\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both the cases, `TesterOne` is dependent on `HelperClass`.

Method 1 lets you inject the dependency, while 2 doesn't. Suppose you need to unit-test `TesterOne`, method 1 easily lets you inject a mock of `HelperClass`.